# How to get customer address by customer ID?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, shipping-address, customer-address

How to get customer address/billing address by customer ID? here's what I've done so far:

```
$customerId = $_POST["customer_id"];
$customer = $this->_customerRepository->getById($customerId);
$address = $this->_addressRepository->getByCustomerId($customerId);//error
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot retrieve an address based on the customer id so this code will never work:

```
$address = $this->_addressRepository->getByCustomerId($customerId);//error
```

Because the `getByCustomerId` method does not exist in the service contract classes.

What you can do though, is use the data service contract customer class with the following code:

```
$customerId = $_POST["customer_id"];
$customer = $this->_customerRepository->getById($customerId);
$addresses = $customer->getAddresses();
```

Please note that `getAddresses` will return an array of `Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface`.

If you need the default billing address you can call:

```
$billingAddress = $customer->getDefaultBilling();
```

Comment: but when i use `$customer->getDefaultBilling();` it return NULL

Comment: @simpleguy that's because the customer you're testing does not have a default billing address probably

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism It is not working for me. Can you please let men know how I can get this details.

Comment: How to get addressID?

Comment: getDefaultBillingAddress

Answer (score 7):

For get customer adderess using order id in .phtml file

```
$customerId = 3;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($customerId);
$customerAddress = array();

foreach ($customerObj->getAddresses() as $address)
{
    $customerAddress[] = $address->toArray();
}

foreach ($customerAddress as $customerAddres) {

    echo $customerAddres['street'];
    echo $customerAddres['city'];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
protected $_address;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Address $address,
    ...     
)
{
    ...
    $this->_address = $address;
    ...
}
```

Use in your function:-

```
$addressObj = $this->_address;
$addressObj->load($addressid);
```

you can get address collection as below:-

```
$addresses = $addressObj->getCollection();
```

Answer (score 0):

$    private $customerFactory;

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
    Context $context
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
}

public function execute()
{
    $customerId = 1;
    $customer = $this->customerFactory->create();
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($customer->getAddressCollection()->addFieldToFilter('parent_id',$customerId)->getData());
}
```