# $customer->getAddressess Error

Tags: magento2, cart, customer, customer-address, address

I am using Magento 2.1.7 CE
sometimes when Im trying modify cart (remove product, add, or update qty) I got Error:
`"Invalid customer address id XX"`.

I noticed that in class `Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException\QuoteAddressValidator`

there is function `validate` with `$applicableAddressIds` variable.
There should be array with all Customer's addresses:

```
        $applicableAddressIds = array_map(function ($address) {
            /** @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface $address */
            return $address->getId();
        }, $this->customerRepository->getById($addressData->getCustomerId())->getAddresses());
```

Unfortunately `getAddresses()` is empty (yes, I checked it).
Customer is not empty.
Someone knows what happens?

Comment: read this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/159754/48564

Comment: I saw it. As you can see this code do exactly what Raphael at Digital Pianism wrote. Alternative way is use ObjectManager to load Customer's model but I prefer to do not do that.