# How can I get Customer's Address?

Tags: magento-2.1, customer-address, object-manager

### Update

***This is not a duplicate of [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/159753/how-to-get-customer-address-by-customer-id).
I've referenced that question, but it didn't give me what I looking for.***

I need to create a file with specific data on customer. I tried few methods I found on here, but no luck. I need to get information as follows,

```
    <Adress>
        <StreetAddress1></StreetAddress1>
        <StreetAddress2></StreetAddress2>
        <City></City>
        <Country></Country>
        <County></County>
        <PostCode></PostCode>
    </Adress>
```

I need to get these info using ObjectManager. I lnow it's not the best way, bou for now, I only able to use it.

**Update**
I need to call these from external file, not as a module or a plugin. So I cannot use any block methods. Only possible way if for me is using the Object Manager directly. But the problem is all the methods I've tried failed.

This below is the code from the answer you guys said my question is duplicate of,

```
$customerId = $_POST["customer_id"];
$customer = $this->_customerRepository->getById($customerId);
$addresses = $customer->getAddresses();
```

but since I'm on outside PHP script, I cant use **$this->_customerRepository** or **$customerRepository** . I'm relatively new to Magento. So I'm not sure how to get things done most of the time.

Comment: @DineshYadav it's not. I just needed a way to get customer default address for external php script. I read that question and tried with it but wasn't successful

Comment: You can get the address details such as city, country etc. from above-mentioned answer.  Then you can use PHP function `file_put_contents` to add the data to your specified file.

Comment: @Joey, you are trying to convince us this is not a duplicate. I could see why, but you are not giving us any details. If this is not a duplicate then I would vote to close your question because it is unclear. Please provide the code you already have so far and **tell us what is the exact problem you have**

Comment: @7ochem I've updated my question a bit. will it be any help?

Comment: @DineshYadav I tried but I failed. also I've updated my question

Comment: @Joey, You can use **customerRepository** with the help of objectManager. Try this `$customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface')->getById($customerId);`

Comment: In order to create an external script (in your m2 webroot) to use magento classes you have to do the next:
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$customer = $obj->get('Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface')->load($customerId);

Comment: @DineshYadav I used my code like this, but still not getting what I needed. **below is my code** $customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->getCollection();
foreach ($customer as $cusitem) {
 $getCustomerId = $cusitem->getData('entity_id');
 $customerDY = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface')->getById($getCustomerId);
 $addressesDY = $customerDY->getAddresses();
 $billingAddressx = $customerDY->getDefaultBilling(); 
 foreach ($addressesDY as $keyzz) {
 print_r($keyzz);
 }
}

Comment: @DineshYadav I used **$addressesDY = $customerDY->getAddresses();** as other question answered. but getting nothing. I checked and most of the customer accounts has set default billing address and shipping addresses. what did I do wrong?

Comment: @PabloGarcia thanks a lot. but when I use your code, I get following error **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository\Interceptor::load()**

Comment: @Joey, Your code is correct but you are printing the complete object which is very large. Use `print_r($keyzz->__toArray());` It will display the customer address in array format.

Comment: @Joey can you post your final solution as an answer? I'm really curious to how you have solved it